# Freemarker and Struts 2 error handling integration

Tags: struts2, freemarker

I have a project where Struts2 provides the MVC layer and FreeMarker templates are used update the web pages. Some of the FreeMarker templates returns partial views - for example addNewRow.ftl which returns a table row. 
Actions are validated and error messages are added to web page using addActionError method. 
In the cases where the web page only receives a partial view, the validation messages aren't getting displayed since the error info is missing from the page. 
 
How can you retrieve and show validation errors occurred in the operation in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just beacuse you elect to redraw a portion of your UI based on a user operation doesn't not mean that is where all that information must be presented.  With the use of jQuery, you could easily take error information and insert it into any existing DOM node on the page, even those that aren't part of the portion of the page you just rendered.

Another solution is to redraw a larger portion of your UI instead that would include the error display container and simply serialize the action messages out during the redraw.

Or you could look at your redraw callback and see whether it can be split into multiple invocations that could each handle their portion of the page redraw independently, e.g: add your table row and render error messages.

Comment: Can you clarify the first suggestion? I can see it working on a Post/Redirect/Get scenario, where you can exclusively return the error information.  In a scenario where data is getting returned - am I correct in thinking your advice is to return the data and errors in separate div elements and then use jQuery to extract them separately?